# Pact.net: Get the request that was sent to the mock service

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, pact

I'm writing the test inside the developers solution for one service and I'm mocking other third-party party services using pact mock service. 
I need to verify the request that was sent to this mock service. So I need to get the payload that was actually sent. (The one that was actually stored into the log file starting with 'Received request ')

I'll greatly appreciate the help

Comment: Which mocking framework are you using? Can we get an idea of the interface?

Comment: Pact.Net - mentioned in the title. https://github.com/SEEK-Jobs/pact-net

Comment: Oh. Right. It's even in the tags. To clarify you want to assert that the request received by the service matches the one you have sent?

Comment: yes, pact put this request to the logs but I need a way to get the same request (preferably not parsing the log)

Comment: Do you, in particular, need the specific request stored in the log? Or is this simply to test the functionality of your code? If it is not just a test what do you need the request for?

Comment: I need to verify that specific data was actually sent. So I need to verify the some values inside the request that was sent

Comment: What is the purpose of verifying this specific data? Would a unit test around this code block not be enough to verify the output?

Answer (score 1):

Pact does the verification of the consumer request for you. Have a look at [this example](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-net#3-write-your-test).

For the consumer, the test process is:

1. Describe the expected request
2. Describe the expected response
3. Call the code that the consumer uses to generate the response. (This step will actually hit the mock server- which returns the expected response if it gets the expected request).
4. Verify that the consumer code returned the expected data
5. **Verify that the mock server received the correct request**

I've bolded step 5, because that's the step that does the checking of the request.

(note also that if the request was not correct, step 3 doesn't generate the correct response, so step 4 will almost always fail)

Here's a breakdown of [the example I linked above](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-net#3-write-your-test) into the consumer test steps I've just listed:

#### Describe the expected request

```
_mockProviderService
  .Given("There is a something with id 'tester'")
  .UponReceiving("A GET request to retrieve the something")
  .With(new ProviderServiceRequest
  {
    Method = HttpVerb.Get,
    Path = "/somethings/tester",
    Headers = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
      { "Accept", "application/json" }
    }
  })
```

#### Describe the expected response

```
 .WillRespondWith(new ProviderServiceResponse
  {
    Status = 200,
    Headers = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
      { "Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8" }
    },
    Body = new //NOTE: Note the case sensitivity here, the body will be serialised as per the casing defined
    {
      id = "tester",
      firstName = "Totally",
      lastName = "Awesome"
    }
  }); //NOTE: WillRespondWith call must come last as it will register the interaction
```

#### Call the code that the consumer uses to generate the response

```
var consumer = new SomethingApiClient(_mockProviderServiceBaseUri);

//Act
var result = consumer.GetSomething("tester");
```

#### Verify that the consumer code returned the expected data

```
//Assert
Assert.Equal("tester", result.id);
```

#### Verify that the mock server received the correct request

```
_mockProviderService.VerifyInteractions(); //NOTE: Verifies that interactions registered on the mock provider are called once and only once
```

^ This is the step you need in order to verify that the request sent was correct.

Comment: Thanks. It is a good answer. I am trying to understand what happens under the hood when 'VerifyInteractions' method is called. I debugged the code and found that it makes call to a method called 'SendAdminHttpRequest' which makes GET call with path /interactions/verifications?example=something and then gets response with string "InteractionMatched". I am not able to understand how test host understands such a GET call and then responds with "InteractionMatched".

Comment: Why do you need to understand what happens under the hood? The mock service verifies that the request matched what you set as the expectation in your test.

Comment: I am just curious as I like to have a deeper understanding of the tool that I am using. I figured it out. Its all part of this codebase. https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-mock_service